# Cannot run under ARM Linux

Tags: .net-core, arm

System environment:

```
Linux 3.10.53-HULK2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 12 19:47:39 CST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux

PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

I have a console app，use of .NET Core 2.x or 3.0

image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/2189761/63394737-a12c1200-c3f3-11e9-9236-eba60d776133.png

```
root@aaa:/tmp/publish# ./libsos.so 
Illegal instruction
root@aaa:/tmp/publish# ./ConsoleApp3
bash: ./ConsoleApp3: No such file or directory
```

Unable to install SDK and Runtime... Even independent publish releases...
This is an industrial development board,I can't run my .NET Core program here.
No matter which version I use，.NET Core 2.x or 3.0.

Comment: How/where did you build your application? What exact version of .NET Core and for which architecture did you install it? What does an `ls` in `/tmp/publish` show you?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the.net core version.I have done a lot of work on arm devices before, but there is no problem.But now it USES huawei Hisilicon processors...

Comment: Which CLR is installed? Mono?